# select a certain element of a list using potition

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists and with 'random.choice' I pick an element from it. Then I want to pick the element of the second list which is in the same position as this of the first one. I manage to get the position of the element of the first list but i don't know how to pick an element from the second list according to the position of the first ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `choice` you could use an approach like this.

Make a random selection of element number using `randint`, then choose that element from each of the lists.

```
>>> import random
>>> list1 = [3, 6, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = [4, 5, 3, 6, 9]
>>> choice1 = random.randint(0, len(list1))
>>> list1[choice1]
1
>>> list2[choice1]
3
```

Comment: is that possible when having strings instead of numbers?

Comment: If you mean when the two lists contain strings rather than numbers then yes.

Comment: are you sure cause when i use this method sometimes i get this error even in the first try: IndexError: list index out of range